# How to compare two elements inside nested arrays using mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I am trying to compare the price between the first and last element inside a nested array.

The following is a part of my data:

```
priceRange:[
   [1600732800000,5.28424438726287],
   [1600819200000,5.08434522342211],
   [1600905600000,3.491229168216385],
   [1600992000000,4.573890580327729],
   [1601078400000,4.702973876095848]
]
```

So in essence I want to know if the ***second element inside the first array*** (5.28424438726287) is bigger than the **second element inside the last array** (4.702973876095848)

---

I have hard time selecting the last array inside the nested array:
The folowing didn't work:

```
$expr: { $gt: [{ $last: "$priceRange" }, 0.000001] }
```

I can select the first element:

```
priceRange.0.1
```

And then there is the question how do you compare them while also having other filter constraints?

```
{name: "Some stock", comparing the prices}
```

---

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add this aggregation stage:

This query create a fields called `isBigger` where compare the values you want:

- The last (second) value from the first array
- The last (second) value from the last array

And the output will be `true` or `false` if is bigger the number or not.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$project": {
      "isBigger": {
        "$cond": {
          "if": {
            "$gt": [
              {
                "$last": {
                  "$first": "$priceRange"
                }
              },
              {
                "$last": {
                  "$last": "$priceRange"
                }
              }
            ]
          },
          "then": true,
          "else": false
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/o5102fTkl6C)

Comment: Thanks. What I would add on top of that is if you need to use find with multiple contraints then the following is an options:

myquery = {
  "$expr": {
    "$and": [
              {"$lt": [{"$last": {"$first": "$priceRange"}},{"$last": {"$last": "$priceRange"}}]},
              {"$gt": ["$market_data.market_cap.usd", 10000000]}
      ]
      }
  }